# Microsoft Excel 2016 3D Maps - better vector data?

Tags: bing-maps

Microsft Excel 2016 comes with a feature called 3D Maps, which charts your spreadsheet data on a vector map base. See [Get Started with 3D Maps](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Get-started-with-3D-Maps-6b56a50d-3c3e-4a9e-a527-eea62a387030).

The data seems to be derived from Bing Maps, which in turn gets its vector data from somewhere else. The coastline vectors are crude, too crude for local mapping. Would it be possible to somehow swap in better coastline vectors?

Answer (score 1):

The 3D maps are using the Bing Maps map tiles. So, no vector data maps there. Bing Maps is constantly working with it's data providers to improve it's data globally, including providing better coastline data.